# crontab does not lauch

Tags: zsh, cron, gnome-terminal

I am trying to launch a `cron job` every hour (an interactive system upgrade).

The code that does the actual update ( a no-password sudo yum update) is in my `.zshrc` (I use `zsh` as my shell). To launch `zsh`, I am invoking a new terminal process, so I have `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` as the process. I have an email from cron saying that the command errorred out with `"Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:"` This is strange, since the command works fine from a terminal.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Whats your cron command look like?  You should probably show that exactly.

Comment: cron jobs do not normally have a /dev/tty, a controlling terminal.  That is the error you are seeing.  Chris gave you a link to the answer. +1